# Rare error when loading a page with Yandex metrics

Tags: vuejs2, yandex-metrika

https://myhost.com/sc.image*https://adfstat.yandex.ru/metrica?id=3945691244*e

When loading a page, at a completely random moment, Yandex Metrica begins to redirect with such a prefix, has anyone seen this?

The script is connected to vue 2 js, there are no custom settings